# Python3.6 dependency missing on AWS Linux 2 AMI with EPEL

Tags: linux, yum, python3, dependencies

Since last Saturday (2019-10-12) it seems that the dependencies for `rlwrap` are broken on Amazon Linux 2 AMI using the EPEL repository. The problem is that `rlwrap` requires Python3.6 (package `python36`), but it is not available from any source. I imagine that a number of packages have this dependency problem at the moment.

Is this an oversight by Amazon Linux or EPEL developers? Or am I doing something wrong?

Is there some way to install `rlwrap` now that the dependencies cannot be found?

**Instructions to reproduce the problem**

On a clean Amazon Linux 2 server, enable the EPEL repository and try to install rlwrap (as root, or use `sudo`):

```bsh
amazon-linux-extras enable epel
yum clean metadata
yum install -y epel-release
yum install -y rlwrap
```

The last command produces the following output:

```
Loaded plugins: extras_suggestions, langpacks, priorities, update-motd
187 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package rlwrap.x86_64 0:0.43-2.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: /usr/bin/python3.6 for package: rlwrap-0.43-2.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Data::Dumper) for package: rlwrap-0.43-2.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libtinfo.so.5()(64bit) for package: rlwrap-0.43-2.el7.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package ncurses-compat-libs.x86_64 0:6.0-8.20170212.amzn2.1.3 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: ncurses-base = 6.0-8.20170212.amzn2.1.3 for package: ncurses-compat-libs-6.0-8.20170212.amzn2.1.3.x86_64
---> Package perl-Data-Dumper.x86_64 0:2.145-3.amzn2.0.2 will be installed
---> Package rlwrap.x86_64 0:0.43-2.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: /usr/bin/python3.6 for package: rlwrap-0.43-2.el7.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package ncurses-base.noarch 0:6.0-8.20170212.amzn2.1.2 will be updated
--> Processing Dependency: ncurses-base = 6.0-8.20170212.amzn2.1.2 for package: ncurses-libs-6.0-8.20170212.amzn2.1.2.x86_64
---> Package ncurses-base.noarch 0:6.0-8.20170212.amzn2.1.3 will be an update
---> Package rlwrap.x86_64 0:0.43-2.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: /usr/bin/python3.6 for package: rlwrap-0.43-2.el7.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package ncurses-libs.x86_64 0:6.0-8.20170212.amzn2.1.2 will be updated
--> Processing Dependency: ncurses-libs(x86-64) = 6.0-8.20170212.amzn2.1.2 for package: ncurses-6.0-8.20170212.amzn2.1.2.x86_64
---> Package ncurses-libs.x86_64 0:6.0-8.20170212.amzn2.1.3 will be an update
---> Package rlwrap.x86_64 0:0.43-2.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: /usr/bin/python3.6 for package: rlwrap-0.43-2.el7.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package ncurses.x86_64 0:6.0-8.20170212.amzn2.1.2 will be updated
---> Package ncurses.x86_64 0:6.0-8.20170212.amzn2.1.3 will be an update
---> Package rlwrap.x86_64 0:0.43-2.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: /usr/bin/python3.6 for package: rlwrap-0.43-2.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /usr/bin/python3.6 for package: rlwrap-0.43-2.el7.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: rlwrap-0.43-2.el7.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: /usr/bin/python3.6
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

**Edit:** The same question is posted to the [AWS Developer Forums](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=311254). Apparently the Amazon Linux team is aware of the incompatibility and are working on a solution.

Answer (score 4):

you have to install `python3` from `amazon-extras` repo:

```
amazon-linux-extras install python3
```

There is a caveat: according to `amazon-linux-extras list | grep python3`,  currently supported version is `3.6.2`, if AWS releases support for `3.7.x` via extras, then install command from above would be vague.

Better to use following:

```
amazon-linux-extras enable python3
yum clean metadata
yum install python3-3.6.* --disablerepo=amzn2-core
```

And then `yum install -y rlwrap` would finish successfully.

Comment: It says "Extra topic has reached end of support." for the amazon-linux-extras "python3". Is there a way to install python36 on AMI2 other than this or building it from sources?

Comment: if it's critical - then only from source and install it as `/usr/bin/python3.6`